# Find The Third One From The First Two Riddles

Tags: riddle, knowledge, movies

---

***HERE IS MY ENTRY TO THE FORTNIGHTLY TOPIC CHALLENGE #1***

---

**First One is the answer of this**

> Even when my eyes are closed, I can see it.
>
> Even when my ears are covered, I can hear it.
>
> Even when my nose is blocked, I can smell it.
>
> Even when my mouth is shut, my tongue can taste it.
>
> Even when my hands are tied, I can touch it.
>
> Even though I can feel it, I am not sure how real is it.
>
> Can you guys feel it, then tell me what is it.

---

**Second one is the answer of this**

> Take one stick. No.
>
> Take another. No.
>
> Take one more. No.
>
> Take a hundred sticks. Yes, that will be it.
>
> Then, what is it?

---

**The real question is to find the third one that is going to be real soon and explain how you get it.**

---

**HINTS**

---

> ***HINT1:*** The answer is a movie name
> ____________________________________
> ***HINT2:*** Answers to first two riddles has a common link (connection), with the help of which you can find the third one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is

> Labor of Love

The 1st part seems to point to

> The Sixth Sense <-- it mentions the normal 5 senses, and then the second to last and last line are asking what is the next one.

The 2nd part I believe refers to

> Unbreakable <-- 3 sticks you can easily break, but a 100?  No way.

Which leads me to believe that these refer to

> M. Night Shyamalan and Bruce Willis movies.

A quick online search showed me the above answer as being in the works.

Comment: I agree, I couldn't get to unbreakable though, nice.

Comment: Great. It's perfect. :)

Answer (score 0):

(Partial Answer)
I'm going to say the answer to the first one is:

> You.

Comment: I am wondering how the "movies" tag connects to the guess?

Comment: It could be that the answers to the first two riddles would be combined with a third answer to make a movie quote. The correct phrasing for the answer to part one might be "I feel ya man" or something along those lines.

Comment: nice line of thought.

Comment: Based on the movies tag, I think the 1st one might be "Sixth Sense."

Comment: @APrough: You are correct about that. Please add it with an explanation as your answer.

Comment: First one makes me think of the Matrix (based on the movie tag)